# Suggestions to reduce request queuing in Rails app on Passenger + Nginix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, nginx, passenger

Our iPhone app is powered by Rails 3.2.12, Nginix 1.4.1, and Passenger. According to New Relic, our methods complete in 200-400 ms. However, some clients don't see results for 20 seconds even though they are on Wi-Fi and the data returned is only 2 MB.

It seems we may have an issue with request queuing. How can we reduce this and improve performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to start by figuring out what it is that's taking so long. Is the db overloaded? in which case - beef up your DB etc. Try digging down into the NewRelic stats and finding out where most of the time is spent (and then post it here).

Comment: The methods all complete, including DB calls, in 200-400 ms. So we don't think it's in the application code since everything looks relatively healthy according to New Relic. It seems like some configuration issue causing some clients not to get data for 20 sec.

Comment: ah, right - I didn't get that from the question. So even the calls that take 20sec experienced-time complete in 200-400ms server-time.

hmmm... interesting.

Just for completeness-sake: do you have client-side javascript?

Comment: yes, the client side JS is what's reporting the slow (> 20 sec) lag time.

Comment: I was actually thinking: is it possible the client-side javascript is actually what is being slow... ;)